# How to echo multiple items from a single column on new line in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, explode

I have two columns in my database that contain values entered from multiple select boxes. I used

```
$skills = join($_POST['skillSelect'],',');
$languages = join($_POST['languageSelect'],',');
```

to format them in the database. Now I want to display them to the user on a different page. They do display, but I want each on different lines. For example, let's say the user entered 'Java, PHP, JavaScript' as their language values. I want them to display as:

```
<p>Java</p>
<p>PHP</p>
<p>JavaScript</p>
```

However, they're just displaying as

```
Java, PHP, JavaScript
```

Here is my attempt using a foreach loop and explode:

```
<?php
    $languages_explode = explode(PHP_EOL, $_SESSION['languages']);
    foreach($languages_explode as $language) {
       echo $language;
     }
?>
```

I also tried:

```
echo "<p>".$language."</p>";
```

I thought the **PHP_EOL** delimiter would format it correctly, but I was wrong. How can I display each item on a new line, preferably within a paragraph tag? Thanks!

Comment: what  `$_SESSION['languages']` contains?

Comment: For my current test user, it contains the values Java, PHP, and JavaScript taken from the database column "Languages".

Comment: change this line `$languages_explode = explode(PHP_EOL, $_SESSION['languages']);` to `$languages_explode = explode(",", $_SESSION['languages']);` and then do `echo "<p>".$language."</p>";`

Comment: @B.Desai If you would kindly post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. :) It worked perfectly! I guess I'll go back to the php manual and see why that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line

```
$languages_explode = explode(PHP_EOL, $_SESSION['languages']);
```

to

```
$languages_explode = explode(",", $_SESSION['languages']);
```

and then do

```
echo "<p>".$language."</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this
your code from db is

```
Java, PHP, JavaScript
```

explode this to convert as array

```
$mystring = "Java, PHP, JavaScript";

$myArray = explode(',',$mystring);

//print_r($myArray);

foreach($myArray as $row)
{
echo "<p>".$row."</p><br>";
}
```

Comment: check you css maybe your css overwrite some thing.. it working in fiddle